"Pseudo-Potential" for acceleration in the $x$ plane?

First Post!
My study group for classical mechanics using Taylor and Thornton and Marion and I found this problem while trying to study for our final. The set up has a particle in a tube that is positioned in the $xy$ plane at some angle theta. The tube also has an acceleration of $a$ in the positive x direction. The problem asks us to use the lagrangian to find the equations of motion. We were having a hard time arriving at an answer we all felt made sense. So, because our professor is okay with us referring to solutions when learning this material, we found a solution online that introduces a "pseudo-potential" which they say is due to the tube's acceleration in the x direction.
I'm not asking for an answer to the problem itself, but instead I am wondering if a "pseudo-potential" makes sense here and what indicates the necessity of introducing it? My professor has never talked about this before and I don't believe I've ever dealt with such a thing.
